# Store and fetch radio button value in different page with javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, local-storage, vuetify.js

I have a radio button field on 3-4 pages, the pages contains same radio buttons but different content below. The radio buttons have a default value, and I want to save the checked value so that when I refresh or go to the other page I can fetch the checked value again.

Each page contains the same radio button section with different content below. I want the result to be: if page 1 chose button "choice 1" then page 2,3 would also display "choice 1" to be checked. I have used localstorage to store and get the radio value but how I fetch the value to display the checked button value after refresh and switch pages.

```
#vuejs 2.6 vuetify 2.3

<template>
…
<v-radio-group v-model=radio row>
    <v-radio label=“choice 1” value=“radio1”></radio>
    <v-radio label=“choice 2” value=“default”></radio>
</v-radio-group>
<h1>Content page 1</h1>

…
</template>

<script>
export default {
    components: {},
    data() {
    …
    radio: “default”,
    …
    },
    methods: {
       saveRadio(value) {
          localStorage.setItem("radio",value);
          console.log(localStorage.getItem("radio"));
       }
    },
   watch: {
      radio(value) {
         this.saveRadio(value);
      }
   }   
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should assign value for radio by value saved on localStorage using hook `mounted`.
`mounted() {
    const radioValue = localStorage.getItem("radio") || "default"
    this.radio = radioValue
  }`

Answer (score 2):

```
export default {
    components: {},
    data() {
      return {
       radio: localStorage.getItem("radio") || “default”,
      }
    },
}
```